# Django Channels - How to get list of groups, a channel was added to?

Tags: django-channels

How can I get a list of all groups, to which a channel was added? I like to have an always open websocket, which stays open, if a user logs in and out. If the user logs out, he should be removed from all groups.

Comment: what I suggest you do is append to the `self.groups` list when you add a group and then you can remove from this group if you need to. Also if the connection closes the webconsumer will remove all these groups.

Comment: I saw in the debugger, that the array self.groups already exists. What is it for? If I add the channel to a group, the array doesn´t get filled automatically. Why doesn´t it get filled? And can I store any data, which I want to save temporarily for this channel, in this consumer as a variable for example as self.testvariable? Also if I use an asynchronous consumer?

Comment: the main use of the array is so you can setup `static` group names that your consumer will get subscribed to on connection. But it is also used when you disconnect to un-subscribe the consumer from all groups.

Comment: yes you can store any values you like on the consumer, each connection gets its own instances of the consumer. this is also true for the async consumer.

Comment: @MatthausWoolard may I know what "self" refers to when you say self.groups? For both the consumer (in my case, an AsyncConsumer) as well as the channel_layer (I'm using the standard RedisChannelLayer), the object has no attribute 'groups'. I solved the above by making my own attribute 'grouplist'. But is there already a built-in list?